# modprobe: FATAL: Module 48723bs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, kubuntu, compiling

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs/wiki/RTL8723BS-module-building-instruction-for-Debian-GNU-Linux), I'm trying to install the WLAN driver for my Odys WinPad 12 on Ubuntu 17.04 with kernel 4.10.0-32. The step for getting the latest kernel was skipped, since I already have a 4.10 kernel on Ubuntu. After the last command `sudo modprobe r8723bs` the following error appears:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module r48723bs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic
```

I'm not familiar with compiling C and drivers on low level base and have no idea what went wrong. I think the compilation didn't work as it should, which is strange, since the compilation process itself returns no errors.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a typo?  The error seems to indicate that you tried to do `sudo modprobe 48723bs` rather than `sudo modprobe r8723bs'

Comment: @Jeremy31: Good one!  Missed that!  See us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) sometime...

Comment: Show us the terminal output for everything from the `make` command on. Please copy/paste that output into your question, not in the comments, please. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. Ping me when you have the info.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes it's a typo, I wrote this question on another computer, since the other one has no internet connection cause of missing WLAN drivers... Sorry for this, I edited my question.

Comment: @heynnema There is no output (expect from `modprobe` as I said), that's the strange thing... But in the meantime I found out, that 4.12 kernel has build in drivers for my WLAN card. From Ubuntu 17 I had 4.10 installed. After manually upgrading from 4.12 my WLAN seems working fine now :)